# Visual Studio style editor for an application-specific scripting language?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsx

Right now I only know about Visual Studio 2008 Shell and the custom control used in the Snippet Compiler.

Also is VS shell suitable for this job? I don't know if it's a custom control or a standalone app? Any tutorials about it?

I would imagine the Snippet Compiler's custom control to be usable and therefore should work, but I still want to know if there are better alternatives out there?

It doesn't have to have everything like step through debuggers which the app itself doesn't support.

My editor will be similar to what Photoshop has for a script editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=59EC6EC3-4273-48A3-BA25-DC925A45584D&displaylang=en)? Also, there are many resources available on [Visual Studio Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't. Mainly because VS extensibility made me think it's about extending VS for VS not anything else.

Comment: Well, it is, except that Visual Studio is a platform intended to be extended for developers of software - that means you and your users!

Comment: Also, if you can hold for VS2010 (or start using the CTP), the entire VS app is now written in WPF and is highly extensible/reusable.

Comment: I see, but before I dig deeper, do you think I can achieve what I need. The scripting language I need to have it run on VS style editor is very simple. It's mostly write and interpret kind of thing. Nothing like what VS has out of the box. I am asking because maybe this kind of extending VS still requires all of its functionality to be fulfilled which I can't due to the language.

Comment: The VS Editors are independent of language compilers. There is no reason you can't do this, and the SDK includes examples of implementing other languages.